# How do I include extra files in my NPM package?

Tags: typescript, tsdx

I am writing my first NPM package. There should be a text file that the program reads from to generate random names. But, whenever I do an NPM build, the "dist" folder doesn't have the text file. I am using tsdx to make this.

Comment: Please add more information to your question. You should also have a look at the [Stack Overflow help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help) (if you haven't already).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.